# I want to use 2d array parameters MATLAB in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab, function

I want to use 2d array parameters, but don't know how.

I can't use `showArray2(...)`.

This is my C# code:

[image: first lazy, atrociously unsearchable code screenshot goes here]

This is my MATLAB function code:

[image: second lazy, atrociously unsearchable code screenshot goes here]
This is my C# code (text):

```
    public static void showSetArray2()
    {
        MWArray[,] arr = new MWArray[2, 3];

        arr[0, 0] = new MWNumericArray(2);
        arr[0, 1] = new MWNumericArray(4);
        arr[0, 2] = new MWNumericArray(6);

        arr[1, 0] = new MWNumericArray(1);
        arr[1, 1] = new MWNumericArray(3);
        arr[1, 2] = new MWNumericArray(5);

        /*
        MWArray[] arr2 = new MWArray[4];

        arr2[0] = new MWNumericArray(2);
        arr2[1] = new MWNumericArray(3);
        arr2[2] = new MWNumericArray(4);
        arr2[3] = new MWNumericArray(5);
        */

        //CsharpClass obj = new CsharpClass();
        CsharpClass2 obj = new CsharpClass2();
        obj.showArrays2(arr);

        obj.Dispose();
    }
```

This is my MATLAB function code (text):

```
    % FileName is 'showArrays2.m'
    function showArrays2(varargin)
        for i=1:nargin
            disp(varargin{i});
        end
    end
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code instead of images

Comment: What is `CsharpClass2`? or `showArrays2` for that matter

Comment: CsharpClass2 is my custom MATLAB class.
It includes the function showArrays2.